# Convert my  google chart to google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to change this:

```
chxl=1:|04:00|05:30|2:|Time|3:|Calories|
&chxr=0,28,362.59
&chxt=y,x,x,y
&chs=900x300
&cht=bvg
&chco=A2C180
&chds=28,362.59
&chbh=a
&chd=t:359,56
```

To a line chart, like this:

```
chs=440x220
&chxt=y,x,x,y
&cht=lc
&chco=3072F3
&chd=t:931.4,23.5,572.4,0,0,0,0
&chds=0,2500
&chxr=0,0,2500|1,1,7,1
&chxl=2:|Time|3:|Calories|
&chdl=Energi
&chdlp=b
&chls=2
&chma=5,5,5,25
&chm=o,000000,0,-1,5
```

I dont know where to put the hours values, 04:00 and 05:30.

What i want to do is display hours on the X and calories on the Y, then it makes a "dot" in the chart for each hour, example 04:00.

How can i change my current chart to a line chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a little confused as the data in your line chart example is very different from your bar chart example (is this deliberate?).

Are you looking for something like this?

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?
chxl=1:|04:00|05:30|2:|Time|3:|Calories|&
chxr=0,28,362.59&
chxt=y,x,x,y&
chs=900x300&
cht=lc&
chco=A2C180&
chds=28,362.59&
chd=t:359,56&
chdl=Energi&
chm=s,000000,0,-1,4
```

Parameter key (from [Google Chart Tools: Image Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html)):

```
chxl - Custom Axis Labels
chxr - Axis Range 
chxt - Visible Axes
chs - Chart Size
cht - Chart Type (bvg - vertical bar chart with grouped bars, lc - line chart)
chco - Series color
chds - Custom scaling
chbh - Bar Width and Spacing (not needed for line chart)
chd - Chart data
chdl - Series display legend. 
chm - Chart marker
```